# To declare a static variable (counter) in a jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I need a counter that is static variable inside a jsp page, how do I do that? or how do I declare a variable inside a jspInit() method?
I need to chceck the number  of hits on that jsp page in its lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
<%! int count; %>
```